# MongoDB $in - only one value and no others

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Wasn't really sure how to title this question, but hope the explanation is clearer

I have a document like

```
{   
_id: "User1",  
skills: [
          {  
           ty: "coding",  
           inf: "c"  
          },
          {  
           ty: "design",  
           inf: "photoshop",  
          },
          {  
           ty: "language",  
           inf: "french",  
          },
          {  
           ty: "language",  
           inf: "german",  
          },
        ]
},
{   
_id: "User2",  
skills: [
          {  
           ty: "coding",  
           inf: "c"  
          },
          {  
           ty: "coding",  
           inf: "scala",  
          },
          {  
           ty: "spreadsheet",  
           inf: "excel",  
          },
          {  
           ty: "language",  
           inf: "english",  
          },
        ]
}
```

And so on, my problem is to select users with only "coding" skills.
Here is what I tried

```
db.collection.find({"skills.ty":{$nin:["language","design","spreadsheet"]}})
```

The problem here is that there is no fixed set of skills. Right now its only (language,design,coding,spreadsheet), but there maybe more in the future.

**How do I write a query to get users with only one type of skill, irrespective of how many others there are?** i.e. *get people who have only coding skills, but no other*

An extrapolation, how to find people with *"coding"* skills in "c" and "c++" but no others?
i.e. *get people who have coding skills in c and c++ and no other coding skills, these users may have other skills like design*

Do I need to write functions for these or is there a query I can write?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with  db.collection.find({"skills.ty":"coding"}) ?

Comment: It returns all objects with skill = coding and other skills as well. Not objects with the only skill being coding.

Comment: I don't have mongodb handy, try retrieving all the skills.ty with distinct/group beside 'coding' then use $nin.

Comment: var allSkills = db.runCommand({ "distinct":"documents",     key:'skills.ty'}).values; This will return all skills, remove the coding and use that in your condition